# Wrong sum result in C code

Tags: c

One operator seems to be produce wrong results in my C code.
First of all, these are the lines of my code where I declare the variables (outside the main function, general scope):

```
FILE *fenergy;
float p1,p2,p3;
float FinalEnergy, EnergyState;
```

Then, I call a function that performs sequentially the next lines of code:

```
p1=FinalEnergy;
p2=EnergyState;
FinalEnergy=FinalEnergy+EnergyState;

fprintf(fenergy,"p1=%f p2=%f   Final=%f",p1,p2,FinalEnergy);
```

The file "fenergy" is correctly started by using the funcion:

```
fenergy=fopen(energy.txt,"w");
```

The values of all the variables seem to be correct in the first million of steps but then, the operation "+" in the line:

```
FinalEnergy=FinalEnergy+EnergyState;
```

Gives a wrong output. This is a sample of the results output from the file written by the fprintf function:

```
p1=-130482984.000000 p2=-23.000000   Final=-130483008.000000 
p1=-130483008.000000 p2=-23.000000   Final=-130483032.000000  
p1=-130483032.000000 p2=-24.000000   Final=-130483056.000000
```

I am getting crazy about this wrong result. There are only a sum operator and three variables, but my code gives that mistaken output.
I have compiled and run my code in both windows 10 (MinGW) and linux (gcc).

I am really lost about this issue.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You realize you're only using 32-bit `float` variables, right?  It looks like you're losing some precision as a result.  Why don't you use 64-bit `double` variables instead?  I personally never, ever use `float` in C.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*. Aside: unless you cannot use `double` for a good reason, do not use the inferior `float`.

Comment: `float` values have 24 bits of precision, which is around 7 decimal digits of precision. You're expecting 9 digits of precision. Use `double` values instead (53 bits = ~16 digits of precision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a rounding error or a problem with accuracy / precision, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon, ... )

maybe try to use `double` instead of `float`

for arbitrary precision you can use special libraries like MPFR ( http://www.mpfr.org/ )

Comment: The problem was solved replacing float with double variables. Thanks for your help!